# one portal to authenticate different applications

Tags: login, security, authentication

I have installed ojs, koha, dspace7 and moodle succesfully on ubuntu 20.04 and I need to use one portal to authenticate the login to all these service, any guide or technical reference I can rely on to make this happen?

many thanks

Comment: if any familiar with shibboleth configuration guide will be greate help